# Use an offline interactive map in QML

Tags: qt, dictionary, qml, openstreetmap

I'd like to inject a chunk of map that I got from [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=7/47.413/1.176&layers=T) under the form of an `osm` file.

From what I've read in the documentation, the [Open Street Map Plugin](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-plugin-osm.html) doesn't seem to have any parameter taking a source file as a map. It only works with a server. Problem is I won't have an Internet connection when running my application. I need to use a map internally.

Ditto for [Mapbox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-plugin-mapbox.html) and [HERE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-plugin-here.html) plugins.

Is there any other way to do this?

Here is the boilerplate to create a Map:

```
Plugin {
    id: somePlugin
    // code here to choose the plugin as necessary
}

Map {
    id: map

    plugin: somePlugin

    center {
        latitude: -27
        longitude: 153
    }
    zoomLevel: map.minimumZoomLevel

    gesture.enabled: true
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update April 2017:** QtLocation now supports offline OSM tiles.
See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-plugin-osm.html

<s>As you note, QtLocation currently does not give you the [offline option](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45732).</s> Also, for basemaps it currently only supports [image tiles](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45284) (not the XML vector OSM data you are talking about).

You have a few alternatives:

In QML: you can use the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Qt](https://developers.arcgis.com/qt/).
Starting from version 10.26 it supports adding custom map layers with offline tiles. You will need to get PNG/JPG tiles of your OSM data first. Here is an [example layer](https://github.com/maply/org-qtmob-arcgis-tiledofflinelayer) that supports OSM slippymap tiles.

In C++: you will find a few options to display vector data that might require or not conversion from the OSM format and more work on your side:

- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Libosmscout
- https://www.mapbox.com/blog/qmapboxgl/
- QGis is made in Qt, as are many other opensource geographic projects, so they might be helpful

Also, don't forget to vote for the issues mentioned above in Qt Bugtracker!

Comment: Despite being the most convenient feature for my problem, ArcGIS is too heavy (700 MB). MaxpboxGL seems to be the most easy way to get an offline map from tiles, but I would need to convert the `QMapboxGL` into a QML object. I wonder if this is feasible.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `QMapboxGL` project does not support Windows. I need my project to be cross-platform.

Comment: The ArcGIS runtime library in your app will be only a few hundred Kbs, so that shouldn't be too much of an issue. On the host machine you'll have to install it at system level though.

Comment: Okay then. I might try it but I have not found the price of the Basic license. It doesn't seem to be free though...

Comment: It is free for this kind of feature which is part of the Basic. You'll just need to register your application on Arcgis Online and get a key - otherwise you'll see a watermark on the map

Comment: Do you know free map layers that I could use to generate tiles from the ArcMap software? I am losing all my hair over this. The map layers that you can find on ArcGIS Online cannot be used to generate tiles packages (see [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102900/create-a-local-tile-package-from-online-world-imagery)).

Comment: Not really. For the tiles, I'd go the OSM way. You can take a look at http://www.thunderforest.com/, for small areas downloading the tiles could be ok (write to the author to make sure - and you'll need a tile download application for OSM). Alternatively use maperitive or something else as described below.

Comment: From what I've seen and tried, ArcGIS only seems to support the tiles generated from its ArcMap software. I have indeed generated a set of tiles from Maperitive but it didn't work. The SDK is looking for a `conf.cdi` file.
Note that my application will be for commercial use.

Comment: the example layer which I posted in my answer supports OSM tiles. It might need some tweaking re. tile location as it has only been tested on Android iOS and OSX. I see no issues with the commercial application as long as you adhere to OSM guidelines regarding attribution

Comment: You mean it supports the OSM configuration? Sorry to be slow on the uptake but I don't find a [property](https://developers.arcgis.com/qt/qml/api-reference/class_tiled_map_service_layer.html) in `TiledMapServiceLayer` that can be pointed out to a folder. 
How is `onRequestTile` called? I guess the tweaking part comes in when the signal is emitted. Seems like `url` is set to a `jpg` file (and the goal would be to set my **tiles.json** file?)

Comment: Yes. In the sample layer the folder is exposed as property tilesResource. As long as you add your own tiles folder and specify the name of the root folder if different from "tiles" you should be up and running. feel free to PM me if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 4):

You can generate or download [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) for offline usage. For generating tiles take a look at [TileMill](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill) or [Maperitive](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive). Downloading tiles can be achieved via [Marble](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Marble) and various other tools, but please respect the tile server's usage policy! Downloading high zoom tiles causes high load on the tile server because these tiles are usually not cached and need to be rendered on the fly.

Comment: Great! I've used Maperitive to generate `png` tiles from my `osm` file. Now I need to use them to generate the map.

Comment: Hello sir, I use the same method to generate png files. However, in my case, there are so many png files -zoom level 10- that I am not able to name every one of them.(The names of png files should apply this pattern osm_100-<l|h>-<map_id>-<z>-<x>-<y>.<extension> as mentioned in QtLocation forum Could I ask, did you encounter the same problem? If you did, how you could overcome it, because as I saw there is no answer. @scai. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. You don't have to name / list every single file. The file names follow a certain pattern. What is your actual problem? Maybe you should create a new question.

Comment: I have used Mapertive to generate png files(tiles) but Mapertive doesn't follow this pattern `osm_100-<l|h>-<map_id>-<z>-<x>-<y>.<extension>`. For example, when I download some tiles at zoom level 10 some png files' names are `202693,202694` etc. Unfortunately, I have to work with at least zoom level 10 and you guess there are many png files that have to be named one by one. I am asking that, if this happened to you too, how did you solve this issue? Or, there may be any other tile creator that follows this pattern? @scai

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138448/qml-offline-map-using-osm-tiles) question is asked by me and [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/95390/qt-offline-maps-using-osm-tiles/9) is the same question that has been asked before. They might be cleaner. @scai

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer that. I've never used Qt to show a map.