# How to save and load cashe for QML Map?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, qt5

How can I save the cache on one computer and load this card cache on another computer where there is no internet, just load the cache from folders?

```
Map {
id: map
z: 0.1
objectName: "map"
anchors.fill: parent
plugin: Plugin { name: "itemsoverlay" }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use an offline interactive map in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647616/use-an-offline-interactive-map-in-qml)

Comment: @Farshid616, No, there is no specifics. The code is focused on png only. But my map has zoom and zoom, which is not suitable for png.

Comment: We have two type of maps first one render vector file, and other one load png tiles that also include different zoom level. to using offline map there are different approach dependent on your plugin, server base or saved tile base. So these are some example maybe help:
Qtwidget slippy map: https://myembeddeddiary.wordpress.com/2016/08/18/building-offline-maps-in-qt-without-any-servertile-server-direct-offline-map-using-file-protocol/
QML ArcGis: https://developers.arcgis.com/qt/latest/qml/sample-code/generate-offline-map/