# QML Offline map using osm tiles

Tags: qt, qml, openstreetmap

I have been trying to prepare an offline Qt map that uses osm tiles -I prepared via Mapertive- and qml. I am using QLocation OSM plugin

```
PluginParameter {
                name: "osm.mapping.offline.directory";
                value: "C:/Users/Halil/yedekleme/Masaüstü/Maperitive/Tiles/Konya/19"
```

to implement my tiles. But as I see it is not completely offline. For example, when I turn off my wifi connection the area that I have created tiles is blurred or not exactly at the same zoom rate or even black. I add a photo to demonstrate that, and it works when I turn on my connection. [image] Additionally, there are some outputs that I checked on the net but didn't understand what they are. For example:

```
QGeoTileProviderOsm: Tileserver disabled at  QUrl("http://maps-redirect.qt.io/osm/5.8/satellite")
QGeoTileFetcherOsm: all providers resolved
QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::error: Internal problem, this method must only be called once.
QHttpNetworkConnectionPrivate::_q_hostLookupFinished could not de-queue request, failed to report HostNotFoundError
```

So what I am doing wrong so it doesn't work correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/05/24/qtlocation-using-offline-map-tiles-openstreetmap-plugin) post can help you.

Comment: @folibis Oh no, is this  osm_100-<l|h>-<map_id>-<z>-<x>-<y>.<extension> talking about png files? Holy! I have almost 100.000k png files and it is impossible to change every name of them.

Comment: I'm not quite sure. The application from the post,  OsmOffline uses png tiles.

Comment: I just checked and yes it means for .png files. Every one of them is needed to be named like in the rule. Thanks.